# Как включить в vim показ блока if elif else

Tags: python, vim

В sublime text есть вот такие линии под if.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сделать такие же лини в vim?

Comment: Чем вам не нравится IDLE или Pycharm?

Comment: @Глеб да просто привык уже работать в консоли.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/articles/224979/ ?